# Xcode 6 side by side editor view

Tags: editor, xcode6

My Xcode is acting really strange, the normal side by side editor view is stacking vertically instead of the normal behaviour in which it becomes just as tabs.

[image: Clicking the two circles (top right) adds the second editor view like this..]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out why the assistant view did not behave as it did previously. It seems the settings was messed up after upgrading to Xcode 6.

[image: This is where you can change where the assistant view places itself.]

Answer (score 8):

For those using XCode 8+

Try `Cmd + Alt + Shift + Click` on a file to unlock some window magic...

Answer (score 3):

In xcode 9 you can press **ALT + CMD + ENTER** to show documents side by side